# What does a double caret in Sage do?

Tags: python, sage

Sage math uses a single caret (`^`) for exponentiation, unlike Python which uses it for XOR.

I'm studying a file `crypto.sage` which has a **double caret**:

```
 assert p^^q == x
```

What does that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the bitwise xor operator like ^ in python:

```
# Sage
sage: 3^^2
1

# Python
>>> 3^2
1
```

For exponentiation:

```
# Sage
sage: 2^8
256

# Python
>>> 2**8
256
```

|  | Sage | Python |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Exponential | ^ | ** |
| Bitwise XOR | ^^ | ^ |